# Как получить такой Json формат PHP?

Tags: json, php

Нужно на выходе от `echo json_encode($array);` получить такой формат **JSON:**

```
var currencies = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Paris' },
    { id: '2', name: 'London' }

  ];
```

Массив **$array** - есть результат от запроса к базе на выборку 2 полей **id** и **name**.

Answer (score 5):

Для того, чтобы `json_encode($array)` вернула результат в требуемом виде, входящие данные должны быть в [таком](http://ideone.com/NIYciY) формате

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Paris'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2', 
        'name' => 'London'
    )
)
```